# ANOVA with a factor dependent variable?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova

I have a dataset where I want to find the relationship between a factor(10 levels) and several independent variables(all numeric). I don't think it will be a good idea to convert the dependent factor to a dummy variable since I have ten levels. Anova seems like the best way to do this but my dependent variable is not numeric. Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: How would you do this problem if the dependent variable were numeric? Let’s start there.

Answer (score 2):

If your dependent variable is ordered (Bad / Okay / Good), you could use a proportional odds logistic regression. If there is no ordering (Apple / Banana / Orange), you can use a multinomial logistic regression.